# How to grant a regular user limited adminsdk access for a google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Is it possible to have a regular user access the AdminDirectory.Members.List() function using google app script without making them an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it's used. You can deploy your script as a web application, executed as yourself and give access to people people within your own domain.

You could set restriction to particular people within your own domain by using Session.getActiveUser() to determine who is accessing it. This won't work unless the user is a part of your own GApps domain.

Comment: The regular user account would be running it as a apps script to check for emails every 5 minutes. I'm not sure what that makes it a web application. How can I give this account access if it runs on their account to check the emails?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more clear with exactly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I've created a google apps user account. That account has a script that runs on a trigger every five minutes. This script checks for any new emails with that five minute trigger. If the script finds a new email it forwards it to a specific email address. In the script I want only the members of a specific group in my google apps domain to be able to have their messages forwarded. I want the script to query the Members.list() function so that I can do a simple check - If message sender is in members.list() then forward, else mark as read and leave without sending.